# CAKeyframeAnimation - Animating an Array of Images creates a huge allocation after completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, cakeyframeanimation

I'm trying to animate an array of `UIImage` with `CAKeyframeAnimation`. Easy in theory.
*Sample code at the bottom of the post.*

My problem is that after the animation did finish, I've got a huge leak that is impossible to get rid of it.

**Code to init `CAKeyframeAnimation`:**

```
- (void)animateImages
{
    CAKeyframeAnimation *keyframeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    keyframeAnimation.values = self.imagesArray;  // array with images

    keyframeAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0f;
    keyframeAnimation.duration = 5.0;

    keyframeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    CALayer *layer = self.animationImageView.layer;

    [layer addAnimation:keyframeAnimation
             forKey:@"flingAnimation"];
}
```

Adding a delegate to the animation and removing the animation manually cause the same leak effect:

```
... // Code to change

keyframeAnimation.delegate = self;

//    keyframeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
keyframeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
keyframeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

....
```

Then:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (flag)
    {
        [self.animationImageView.layer removeAllAnimations];
        [self.animationImageView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"flingAnimation"]; // just in case
    }
}
```

The result is always a huge allocation. The size of the stack of memory is proportional to the size of the images:

[image]

[I uploaded an example to GitHub to check the code.](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/KeyAnimationLeak)

Comment: I run the instrument and there is no leak but allocation is high.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve the high allocation?

Comment: Use `imageWithContentsOfFile` instead.

Comment: Just set your image array to nil when animation is done.

Comment: This is not working. That was the first thing I tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I found the problem.

As [gabbler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4016786/gabbler) was saying there was not a leak problem. The problem was a high allocation of Images.

I was releasing the array with the images, however, the images did not disappear from memory.

So finally I found the problem:

```
    [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
```

From method definition:

`This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method locates and loads the image data from disk or asset catelog, and then returns the resulting object. You can not assume that this method is thread safe.`

So, `imageNamed:` stores the image in a private Cache.
- The first problem is that you can not take control of the cache size.
- The second problem is that the cache did not get cleaned in time and if you are allocating a lot of images with `imageNamed:`, your app, probably, will crash.

**SOLUTION**:

Allocate images directly from Bundle:

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageName.png"];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName

// Allocating images with imageWithContentsOfFile makes images to do not cache.
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

**Small problem**:

Images in `Images.xcassets` get never allocated. So, move your images outside Images.xcassets to allocate directly from Bundle.

[Example project with solution here.](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/CAKeyframeAnimationExample)

Comment: Add 300 images and you solution will not work either :D

Comment: But i cannot use video as i need to put the images on video with the help of AVMutableVideoComposition by adding a CALayer and putting CAKeyframeAnimation. (As using video will not have the alpha like PNG images have).

Your suggestion for using video is good if i have to show the animation on the UI but in my case i need to save the animation on Video also..
Thanks in advance for any help :)